# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectionChange') at push

Tags: angular

this is my code i dont know why it error:
this is the file ListStaffComponent:

```
export class ListStaffComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() simpleView: boolean = false;
    @Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

```
selectRow(item: any) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.selectionChange.emit(item);
}
```

this is the file staffManagementComponent:

```
ngOnInit():void {
    this.staffManagement.selectionChange.subscribe(data => {
        this.qcTestSelect = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: please add more detail to this post, for example "what language am i using", "What error am I receiving".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `staffManagement` is a ViewChild. ViewChild's are not available at `ngOnInit`.

**Solution 1**

Move the subscription to `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit():void {
  this.staffManagement.selectionChange.subscribe(data => {
    this.qcTestSelect = data;
  });
}
```

**Solution 2 (recommended by me)**

Forget about the ViewChild and use the event directly in your template

*html*

```
<list-staff [simpleView]="myBoolean" (selectionChange)="setData($event)"></list-staff>
```

*ts*

```
setData(item) {
  this.qcTestSelect = item;
}
```